# C++ Qpainter rotate

Tags: c++, qt, qpainter

Есть 2 объекта , первый смещается с помощью rotate , второй же нет . Могу ли я как либо узнать координаты первого на плоскости без смещения , то есть на координатной плоскости второго?
Это нужно для правильного сравнения этих двух объектов.

Comment: не понял, вы хотите узнать координаты первого объекта относитльного второго?

Comment: Да, нужно узнать координаты первого на плоскости второго, чтобы сравнить эти два объекта.

Comment: Надо координаты второго объекта вычесть из первого

Comment: @Zamlax на плоскости второго - что это значит? Они что не в одной плоскости что ли? Если не в одной, то это не возможно, с если в одной, то говорите по нормальному: относительно второго объекта

Comment: Это можно сделать взяв две абсолютные координаты и вычесть одну из другой. Также можно воспользоваться методом OGraphicsItem::mapToItem